# If I want to call SSL_shutdown() with non-blocking sockets, do I need to keep calling SSL_read() first until it yields SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ssl, openssl

Given a scenario where:

- multiple SSL/TLS records have arrived on a single socket
- those records are parsed one at a time with `SSL_read()` (and a large enough buffer to hold them).
- prior to parsing the final record buffered at the SSL layer, I detect invalid application data and want to close the connection without parsing the remaining incoming data

Will `SSL_shutdown()` discard any remaining SSL read data on the socket for which I haven't called `SSL_read()` read yet, or do I always need to just keep on calling `SSL_read()` first until it yields `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` (which would waste CPU cycles extracting data I don't even care about anymore) and then call `SSL_shutdown()`?

What concerns me is that `SSL_shutdown()` too can yield `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` (according to the man page at least), but if for whatever reason there is still unread data on the socket, I won't necessarily be notified of new incoming packets because of how I use `epoll_wait()`.

Comment: Ugh. After typing all that, I realized just now that packets can arrive in between calls to `SSL_read()` and `SSL_shutdown()`, regardless of how often I call `SSL_read()`, so I guess it's safe to assume `SSL_shutdown()` does the required cleaning for me(?)

Comment: Wow, why would anyone vote to close this because it's "too localized"? That's just ridiculous. Openssl is the de facto crypto library out there (for better or rather for worse). Shutting down SSL connections is one of its core functions. Using non-blocking sockets is recommended practice these days. Not even `epoll()` is obscure anymore. Maybe you just thought it was funny to shutdown a question about shutting down a connection? In that case, touche!

Answer (score 0):

Checked the ssl_shutdown code of openssl as well as documentation.. There is no mention of the cleanup done as part of the shutdown. It appears to send just the Close notification to the peer and set state to appropriate state.

I feel the cleanup u are looking for will be done when SSL_free(ssl) will be called. (just my thought as haven't checked the free code deeply).